WPF DataGrid defined in DataTemplate using CollectionViewSource for sorting does not sort when recycled
Here I have a View defined in XAML like this : A first DataGrid displays a list of rows. When the user selects a row, a ContentControl displays informations about this selected item, including a list of sub items. These sub items are displayed in another DataGrid. Each sub item has a property Index used to define the sorting order of the sub items, by using a CollectionViewSource in the ContentControl's Resources. The sub items DataGrid has its property ItemsSource binded to the CollectionViewSource.
<Grid>
    <!-- define two columns -->
    <DataGrid x:Name="ItemsDataGrid"
              Grid.Column="0"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              ItemsSource={Binding Items}>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
             ....
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1"
                    Content="{Binding ElementName=ItemsDataGrid, Path=SelectedItem}">
        <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:MyUserControl />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>

And this is how MyUserControl is defined in XAML :
xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedSubItems"
                              Source="{Binding SubItems}">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Index" />
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DataGrid x:Name="SubItemsDataGrid"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedSubItems}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
           ....
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>

The Index property is not used in a DataGrid Column. It is used to provide users a way to place subitems in the exact order they want by clicking on Buttons (Move up and Move down). The sorting works fine when the first item is selected. However, as soon as the user select another item, the SubItemsDataGrid doesn't display the subitems in the sorted order. Even by re-selecting the first item the sorting doesn't work anymore.
What I have tried is to use an ItemsContol instead of the DataGrid to be sure that the CollectionViewSource provides a proper ordered list. It's working.
Then I tried to hook DdataContextChanged event of DataGrid in which I wrote a code to replace the itemsSource :
private void SubItemsDataGrid_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)

{
    DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
    dg.ItemsSource = null;
    ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(((IEnumerable<ItemClass>)dg.DataContext).SubItems);
    view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Index", ListSortingOrder.Ascending));
    view.Refresh();
    dg.ItemsSource = view;
}

I tried many other variations of assigning ItemsSource of the DataGrid but they all failed. It seems that DataGrid is managing the sorting in a hidden way.
I also tried to have the DataGrid defined in its own DataTemplate and to inflate it each time the DataContextChanged event was fired for the MyUserControl element.
The question is : Do you know how to force the DataGrid to accept the incoming sorted list? Or do you know another way of doing all that, knowing that I chose the DataGrid because it has the new-item-creation and item-deletion builted-in?
EDIT I've also tried to define a hidden column in the DataGrid binded to the Index property and set the DataGrid to be sorted from this hidden column but it's not working :
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Index"
                    Width="Auto"
                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                    Binding="{Binding Index}"
                    SortDirection="Ascending"/>


After a few hours of seeking a solution, I found one and therefore I can answer my own question.
The core of the problem resides in two facts mixed together:

WPF re-uses the UIElements to avoid re-constructing them. The DataTemplate which provides the content of the ContentControl always give the same instance of its root UIElement once it has been inflated. So only the DataContext changes for the ContentControl and its children (in this case the DataGrid).
DataGrid has a strange behavior when its ItemsSource property is binded to a sorted CollectionViewSource and when its DataContext changes. It reacts like it's rejecting the sorted list while accepting the items.

That being understood, the answer is actually quite simple : the MyUserControl must be re-construct each time the selected row changes because it's the only way to break the DataGrid weird behavior of not accepting sorted CollectionViewSource items when the DataContext changes.
So this is what I came up with :
Instead of providing the ContentControl a DataTemplate an binding its Content to the SelectedItem, I hook the SelectionChanged event of DataGrid in the code-behind to replace the ContentControl's Content with a new instance of MyUserControl.
<Grid>
    <!-- define two columns -->
    <DataGrid x:Name="ItemsDataGrid"
              Grid.Column="0"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              ItemsSource={Binding Items}
              SelectionChanged="ItemsDataGrid_SelectionChanged">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
             ....
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1"
                    x:Name="EditionContentControl" />
</Grid>

And in code-behind (the MyUserControl XAML is left unchanged):
private void ItemsDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
    EditionContentControl.Content = new MyUserControl() { DataContext = dg.SelectedItem };
}

